# How do I choose which parameters to estimate in an ARMA model in python statsmodel?

Tags: python, time-series, data-analysis, statsmodels

Say I have come to the conclusion that the model for a specific data set should be an ARMA model with parameters a1, a2, a3, a9, a10, a11 and c1, c2, c3, c9, c10, c11, c12.

How can I do a model fitting using only these parameters, and thus setting all other possible parameters to zero?

Comment: This is most definitely a [cross validated/ stats exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com) question.

Comment: AFAIR, SARIMAX has the option of using only specified lags. ARMA in statsmodels does not allow gaps in the list of lags.